# Can we make jetifier work with generated code

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

If you use an annotation processor that generates code and is not yet converted to android x, the generated code of course may contain app compat imports.

Sadly, be default, the jetifier is not converting this code. Is there any way to solve this other than waiting for a library update or updating the library by myself?